# Android Studio - How can I take latest code backup from workspace?

Tags: android, android-studio, export

I am taking backup from workspace folder as a zip file but when I see the code after extract It shows me some Old codes maybe Android studio save it in Some temp file.

I want to fix this because If copy and paste from Workspace is not working than backup is useless.

Comment: Use github for better approach

Comment: Even local git repository is enough for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GitHub](https://github.com/).It is a Web-based Git repository hosting service. It offers all of the distributed revision control and **`source code management (SCM) functionality of Git as well as adding its own features`**.

Comment: I do not want to share my code.I want to do it locally

Comment: Bitbucket is free and private (with 5 )

Comment: I know these are the alternate options.What is local git?

Comment: @KDOSHI Sorry for my wrong explanation above . As per your requirement you must use `BitBucket` instead of `GitHub` .

Comment: I want Local backup only like eclipse export project.

Answer (score 0):

You should use git solutions. Check this out https://bitbucket.org. It's private and free.